# Not able to get angular-ui-bootstrap to work on Single page app with angularjs1.5

Tags: angularjs, gulp, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm having issues with getting angular ui bootstrap to work in my single page angular 1.5 app. I'm serving the app with gulpjs and I'm not getting any errors. my app is structes as such:

[image: file structure]

## auth-form.component.js

```
var authForm = {
  bindings: {
    user: '<',
    button: '@',
    message: '@',
    onSubmit: '&'
  },
  templateUrl: './auth-form.html',
  controller: 'AuthFormController'
};

angular
  .module('components.auth')
  .component('authForm', authForm);
```

## auth-form.module.js:

```
angular
  .module('components.auth', [
    'ui.router',
    'firebase',
    'ui.bootstrap'
  ])

//  .config(function ($firebaseRefProvider) {
    // Initialize Firebase 
//...
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="root" ng-strict-di>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Urban Farmer</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <root>
      <span class="loader">Loading...</span>
    </root>

    <div>
      <button type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-warning">buttons</button>

    </div>
    <script src="js/vendor.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm simply trying to use the btn btn-primary class on my login button, but it doesn't seem to be working. I expect I'm not adding the 'ui.bootstrap' dependency in the correct file. Any thoughts?

It wasn't working in the auth-form.html, so I thought I'd try it in the index file but even still it's not working

Comment: Seems like core angularjs library is missing.

Comment: angularjs is included in the bundler.js file. Ideally I would have the last four script elements because those would all be included in the bundle as well. The issue I'm having is the angular-ui-bootstrap directories aren't working.

Comment: The `angular.module` statement with dependencies should be included before the `angular.module` statement with the `authForm` component.

Comment: The `bootstrap.min.js` file is not needed and may conflict with `angular-ui-bootstrap`. Also what version of `ui-bootstrap` are you running? The directive names were changed to be prefixed with `uib-` with the release of 1.0.